# How to grep the whole quote when a specific string is within

Tags: linux, grep

For example I have

```
"Cloud Sun 01/01/2000" 
"Winter Summer Autumn" 
"Cloud Moon 01/01/2200" 
"Cloud Earth 01/01/2120" 
"Warm Hot Cool"
```

I want to grep all the quotes that has the word 'Cloud' in it, giving me

```
"Cloud Sun 01/01/2000" 
"Cloud Moon 01/01/2200" 
"Cloud Earth 01/01/2120"
```

I have tried `grep ".* Cloud .*"`, which I thought it would stop when there's " at the front and back

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try the following solution once.

```
grep "\"Cloud.*" file
```

Using grep to match "Cloud and escaping " to match exact quote. Also you need not to use .* before Cloud because your lines starts with "Cloud

Comment: Hey, I've tried your solution however it highlights every other "example" behind/infront of it.

"Cloud Sun 01/01/2000" 
"Winter Summer Autumn" 
[ABCDEF]
"Cloud Moon 01/01/2200" 
"Cloud Earth 01/01/2120" 
"Warm Hot Cool" 
[OPQRST]

taking this for example, it will highlight every "anything" except [].
However I only want it to highlight the ones with 'cloud' in it, and exclude "winter summer autumn" and "warm hot cool"

Comment: @john, my code is working as per your sample. Would request you to please provide me more samples , so that if require we can refine the solution accordingly.